# log4net failed to produce an expected file name

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have log4net with version 2.0.8, which is updated from the older version 1.2.10.

I am trying to generate a log file and it needs rolling based on Composite mode. But there is a problem with file name when generating.

1st time: (working fine)
**Expected output:** "Error.2019-06-06.UmPortalAppServer.log"*(created:2019-06-06)*
**Actual output:** "Error.2019-06-06.UmPortalAppServer.log"*(created:2019-06-06)*

2nd time:(this is the Issue-1: when after 1st rolling - newly created file name displayed as yesterday's date with filename)
**Expected output:** "Error.2019-06-07.UmPortalAppServer.log"(created:2019-06-07)
**Actual output:** "Error.2019-06-06.UmPortalAppServer.log"*(created:2019-06-07)***(issue*)**

2nd time:(this is the Issue-2: when after 1st rolling - previous log file get updated)
**Expected output**: "Error.2019-06-06.UmPortalAppServer.log"(maintain the previous log)
**Actual output**: "Error.2019-06-06.UmPortalAppServer2019-06-06.log"**(issue*)**

**Expectation:**
Issue-1. All newly generated logs file name should get the current date and time.
Issue-2. All previous logs file name should NOT change.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<appender name="Error" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{logpath}Error6.%date{yyyy-MM-dd}.%property{module}.log" />
    <appendToFile value="false"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="50MB"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
    <countDirection value="1"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{ISO8601}|%property{jobid}|%property{module}|%property{channel}|%-5level|%2thread|%message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: _"public bool StaticLogFileName { get; set; }

true if always should be logged **to the same file**, otherwise false. "_ - Switch this off, then try again and see if one or both of the issues go away. Clear the logfile folder of logfiles before you try.

Comment: I did try like that too. It generates file name like "Error.2019-06-06.UmPortalAppServer2019-06-06.0.log" for the first generated log file.

But the expected one is : "Error.2019-06-06.UmPortalAppServer.log"

Comment: The main problem with "%date{yyyy-MM-dd}" pattern.

Comment: It always tries to print the date like: "Error2019-06-06.log.0.UmPortalAppServer" when after changing the pattern like "<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{logpath}Error.%property{module}" />"

Comment: @AB-141I think the `$filename.0.log` is because you tell it to keep 100 backup files per day. Somehow the rolling file appender needs to keep track of how many backups there are and which one is the last recent.

Comment: @waka, actually, the problem is not only with the `0.log`. "2019-06-06.0.log" portion tries to append with the filename for the recent existing file every time. But, I need to avoid that action to rename the recent existing file.